# JavaFX TextArea scrollbar move event

Tags: java, javafx, scroll, textarea

I need to add "scrollbar move" listener to a `TextArea`.

But when I added

```
textArea.addEventFilter(ScrollEvent.ANY, (x) -> System.out.println(textArea.getScrollTop()));
```

It is only listening to events triggered by using mousewheel - mousewheel scroll.

**When I pick scrollbar by mouse a drag it up and down, no event is caught.**

I've tried different approach

```
textArea.addEventFilter(ActionEvent.ANY, (x) -> System.out.println(textArea.getScrollTop())); 
textArea.setOnScroll(...);
textArea.setOnScrollStarted(...);
textArea.setOnScrollFinished(...);
textArea.textProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
   System.out.println("> " + textArea.getScrollTop());
});
```

Nothing is responding to scrolling using scrollbar.

How can I catch such an event ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [`scrollLeftProperty`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/TextArea.html#scrollLeftProperty) property

> The number of pixels by which the content is horizontally scrolled.

and the [`scrollTopProperty`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/TextArea.html#scrollTopProperty) property

> The number of pixels by which the content is vertically scrolled.

of the `TextArea` to be listened:

```
TextArea ta = new TextArea();
ta.scrollTopProperty().addListener((obs, oldVal, newVal) -> 
    System.out.println("Position from top: " + newVal);

ta.scrollLeftProperty().addListener((obs, oldVal, newVal) -> 
    System.out.println("Position from left: " + newVal));
```

Sample output:

```
Position from top: 36.0
Position from left: 16.6046511627907
```